# Dynamic Typescript props on dynamic react components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dynamic, components

The problem is, I have a set of components

```
const EquationOptions = (props: Equation) => { … }
const GridOptions = (props: Grid) => { … }
const OptionGroupOptions = (props: OptionGroup) => { … }
const PageOptions = (props: Page) => { … }
const SectionOptions = (props: Section) => { … }
const TableOptions = (props: Table) => { … }

const containerOptions = {
    Equation: EquationOptions,
    Grid: GridOptions,
    "Option Group": OptionGroupOptions,
    Page: PageOptions,
    Section: SectionOptions,
    Table: TableOptions,
};
```

And I am trying to set components dynamically as follow:

```
if (activeComponent) {
    const ComponentOptions = containerOptions[activeComponent?.componentType];
    options = <ComponentOptions {...activeComponent} />;
  }
```

Where the activeComponent variable has the type:

```
type ContainerModels = Equation | Grid | OptionGroup | Page | Section | Table;
```

The editor keeps showing an error on the ComponentOptions tag:

Type '{ variables: string[]; equation: string; componentType: "Equation" | "Grid" | "Option Group" | "Page" | "Section" | "Table"; uid: string; formComponentType: FormComponentType; identifier: string; caption: string; hint: string; } | ... 4 more ... | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Equation & Grid & OptionGroup & Page & Section & Table'.
Type '{ variables: string[]; equation: string; componentType: "Equation" | "Grid" | "Option Group" | "Page" | "Section" | "Table"; uid: string; formComponentType: FormComponentType; identifier: string; caption: string; hint: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Grid': templateRows, templateColumns

Though the program works because it always pass the correct type for props in the tag, I don’t know how to let typescript infer the type of the props I am passing.

Comment: What are some examples of these models?

Comment: Look I recommend just using an exhaustive `switch` statement. switch (activeComponent?.componentType) case <MyComponent {...activeComponent}`

Comment: `is missing the following properties from type 'Grid': templateRows, templateColumns`. It sounds like the type system is working fine, this is saying you aren't passing the correct props to the Grid component. my guess would be that `activeComponent` is not typed correctly, so when you extend it on your component (aka here `<ComponentOptions {...activeComponent} />`) it doesn't think its received `templateRows` or  `templateColumns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem just by giving a correct type to the containerOptions:

```
interface ContainerOptions {
    [key: string]: Function;
}

export const containerOptions: ContainerOptions = {
    Equation: EquationOptions,
    Grid: GridOptions,
    "Option Group": OptionGroupOptions,
    Page: PageOptions,
    Section: SectionOptions,
    Table: TableOptions,
};
```

Comment: This is just hiding the issue under some generic types, not strongly typing your props by component type. I would consider this a regression in the code.